# git rebase silently picked the wrong file version

Tags: git, rebase

To merge a branch via a `-ff-only` PR I did the following steps to rebase it:

```
git fetch
git checkout feature/FOO
git pull
git rebase origin/master
```

There were a few conflicts which I resolved by fixing the files in the working tree, `git add`ing them and doing `git rebase --continue`. Finally I did `git push --force` and someone else (the branch owner) created a PR.

Today we found out that one of the files that wasn't touched in `feature/FOO`, but was updated in `master` got included in the PR, overwriting some changes already pushed to `master`.

1. Why did this happen?
2. What have I done wrong when rebasing?
3. How should I correctly rebase the branch in such cases?

Comment: I didn't, I force pushed the feature branch.

Comment: Your commands seem to be correct!
Without seeing the actual commits it is hard to say what might have happened.
Can you reproduce this rebase? That is, you can still access the original F00 branch (before the rebase and force push) and does a rebase as you describe lead to the same flawed result?